# A audio book about two children and an apprentice wizard?

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, wizards, audio-book

I remember back when I was a child (late nineties), I listened to some audiotapes. One of them was story about two children, and a wizard who accidentally teleports into them when he is trying to pass his wizarding exams. They go off on all sorts of adventures, teleporting to different worlds, before realizing the wizard has grown in confidence and needs to go back to retake his test.

I listened to this tape in the late nineties, but the tapes (and therefore the story) might be older.

Does anyone recognise this story? Could you name it?

Comment: Could you narrow down "when I was a child" to a specific year/decade?

Comment: I can narrow it down to when I *listened* it, but I don't know if it's much good as the tapes were likely from a charity shop and quite old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was just thinking about this series and was trying to find its name. On the way I stumbled across this question, which I am now hopefully in a position to answer.

I believe it is *[The Wizard in the Woods](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1687949.The_Wizard_in_the_Woods)* (first published in 1990) by Jean Ure. Book 1 of the Wizard Trilogy (followed by the sequels *Wizard in Wonderland* (1993) and *Wizard and the Witch* (1995)).

The wizard in question is named Ben-Muzzy and the children (twins) are named Gemma and Joel.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the [magic tree house](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Tree_House_series) books? I haven't listened to any of them, but I have read a few with the kids and it sounds to be along the same lines.

Comment: Unfortunatley not. Neither Morgan LF or Merlin are apprentices.